# Concurrent TCP server using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm trying to create a concurrent TCP server which accepts multiple(N connections) where N is known.(e.g.N=8) So I'm trying to create a prethreaded TCP server.

.....

```
    for(i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS;i++)
    {
       CreateThreads(i);         
    }

    return 0;
}

//Create threads to handle the connection
void CreateThreads( int i )
{
  pthread_create(&thread_tid[i], NULL, thread_function, (void *) i);

  return; 
}

void* thread_function(void *arg)
{
        puts("In thread_function");
        int    client_soc,clilen;

        struct sockaddr_in *clientaddr;

        if( (clientaddr = malloc(addrlen)) == NULL)
          printf("malloc Error\n");

        printf("thread %d starting\n", (int) arg);
        while(1)
        {

                clilen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mlock);

                puts("Calling accept \n");
                if ( (client_soc = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr,(socklen_t*)&clilen)) < 0)
                {
                    printf("accept error\n");
                }
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mlock);

                printf("Process Request...calling connection handler \n");
                connection_handler(client_soc);              /* process request */
                close(client_soc);
        }
}

//This will handle connection for each client
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Receive and process.....  
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code threads are created and the thread_function() gets called but it doesn't work as expected. The program comes to an end after calling the thread_function() till then a few threads get created.
I actually want the "N" number of threads to get created and wait for clients to connect(using accept()). Once connected i want to receive/collect data (or) sending commands etc. That's the reason i have connection_handler() but i'm stuck before that.

Can any one pls try to correct the thread_function() function ? I'm kind of getting stuck here.Thanks.
**UPDATE**
The program is based on the 
http://www.cse.fau.edu/~jie/research/publications/Publication_files/roussevwu.pdf
 Look at section 3.2 for using lock and accept.

Comment: Why is it voted close. Please add a comment before you vote.It helps !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The program comes to an end after calling the thread_function()

The problem is that after you create the threads the main thread falls through and ends the program. You should call `pthread_join`.

---

There's a problem with your approach. In your code you lock `mlock` and then you `accept(2)`. You are calling a blocking function **in a critical section**. This severely limits parallelism, thus defeating much of the purpose of the threads.

You could try an approach where the main thread `accept`s and dispatches the new sockets to threads.

Comment: I thought we can speedup by creating a pool of threads when the server starts, instead of creating a new thread for every client after accept() from main().

Comment: @m4n07 And it's a good idea. That's what I meant by "dispatch". You don't have to create thread, you can use pre-created ones.

Comment: Once i create a bunch of threads using pthread_create(..,..,funcName,..) , Once created it calls the function which i specify.  Once i created the thread in main , how do i wait till the client establishes connection over accept(). And call the funcName()

Comment: @m4n07 I'm not sure where to begin. Look for some thread pool examples ? Use some condition variables ?

Comment: http://www.cse.fau.edu/~jie/research/publications/Publication_files/roussevwu.pdf Looking at section 3.2 for using lock and accept.